# Is it possible to execute a remote batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is it possible to execute a remote batch file without using any tool?(I don't want to use psexec) I've tried this one but didn't work:

```
net use j: \\machine01\c$ pass \user:admin  
j:\batch.bat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is to use `psexec`. I can't imagine why you wouldn't want to use the perfect tool for the job.

Comment: @Igurama That comment makes no sense to me.